# Docker: how control docker service on host from it's container?

Tags: docker

There is possibility to install docker in docker container.

How to control docker host service from it's container (manage another containers)?

If execute `docker run --privileged=true -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $(which docker):$(which docker) -ti debian` and enter docker error appears:

`docker: error while loading shared libraries: libapparmor.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your host is a linux based machine, you dont need to install docker inside container, you can just mount docker into container and whatever you do with that inside your container is just like doing it on host. I have tested it on a Ubuntu machine (image: https://github.com/mohamnag/ubuntu-git.git) by mounting `/usr/bin/docker` from host into `/bin/docker` inside container. then inside that container you can literally do (build, stop, list ...) whatever you may have done with docker inside host.

Comment: dont work. error: `no permission to read from '/dev/input/event11`

Comment: what is exactly your host machine? and why the name `/dev/input/event11`?

Comment: linux mint 17.2 ; I dont know.

Comment: that could be depending on how docker installation and permissions varies between a pure ubuntu and mint. I see you already succeed by installing docker inside container, thats a safe option and should work always. but I successfully use that image and mounting /usr/bin/docker into it. if your interested into this faster way, maybe just try to find the docker on host (`which docker`) and give docker user all permissions to it, just for test.

Comment: PS: my host is Ubuntu Server 14.04

Comment: I install docker through official shell script installer.

Comment: The OP is already mounting docker into the container; that's exactly what `-v $(which docker):$(which docker)` is doing it the question.  And the error is because that particular docker binary has requirements that are not met inside the container.

Comment: if somebody still looking for some good recommendation from a docker core developer here it comes: http://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/

Answer (score 2):

The error you're seeing seems very clear: the `docker` binary requires a shared library that is not present inside the container.

Is your container running the same distribution and version as your host?  If it is, you simply need to determine which packages provide the necessary dependencies and install them inside the container.

If not, you will probably have better luck simply *installing* `docker` inside the container, rather than trying to bind-mount it from the host.  There is probably a source of recent Docker versions available for Debian.